# Hide navbar title

Tags: css, r, shiny, navbar

I am working on a Shiny app with a navbarPage with plenty of tabPanels. Here is a minimal example:

```
ui <- navbarPage(
  'example', collapsible=TRUE,
  tabPanel("panel 01", 'some text'), tabPanel("panel 02"), tabPanel("panel 03"), 
  tabPanel("panel 04"), tabPanel("panel 05"), tabPanel("panel 06"), 
  tabPanel("panel 07"), tabPanel("panel 08"), tabPanel("panel 09"), 
  tabPanel("panel 10"), tabPanel("panel 11"), tabPanel("panel 12")
)
server <- function(input, output){}  
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Now, if the screen is wide enough, the tabs align nicely with the title, looking like this:
[image: 01]

However, in a smaller window, the panels do not fit in one row anymore, resulting in this:
[image: 02]

The panel headers are moved to a row below the title, basically wasting a lot of space in the title row. This is especially annoying since I have the title set to "" or `NULL`, resulting in an empty row:
[image: 03]

Is there a way to remove/hide this empty row? I have tried messing around with style tags, but nothing came even close to fixing this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the `navbar-brand` with `.css` by setting `{display:none}`. For this you need to adapt your UI a bit. Because you are using `navbarPage` you need to add the `tagList` function. If you don't wrap it in a taglist shiny will think that you want to create a new `tabPanel` and a ghost tab will appear. More info [here.](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/827)

**A working example:**

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  tagList(tags$head(tags$style(type = 'text/css','.navbar-brand{display:none;}')),
          navbarPage(
            '', collapsible=TRUE,
            tabPanel("panel 01", 'some text'), tabPanel("panel 02"), tabPanel("panel 03"), 
            tabPanel("panel 04"), tabPanel("panel 05"), tabPanel("panel 06"), 
            tabPanel("panel 07"), tabPanel("panel 08"), tabPanel("panel 09"), 
            tabPanel("panel 10"), tabPanel("panel 11"), tabPanel("panel 12")
          )))

server <- function(input, output){}  
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```